# Set fields with reflection - String has no valueOf(String) method

Tags: java, string, reflection, value-of

I'm setting public fields of the `Object` `this` via reflection. Both the field name and the value are given as `String`. I use several various field types: `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, an own `enum`, and a `String`.

It works with all of them **except with a `String`**. The exception that gets thrown is that no method with the signature `String.valueOf(String)` exists... Now I use a dirty `instanceof` workaround to detect if each field is a String and in that case just copy the value to the field.

```
private void setField(String field, String value) throws Exception {
   Field wField = this.getClass().getField(field);

   if(wField.get(this) instanceof String){ //TODO dirrrrty hack
    //stupid workaround as java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.String) fails...
    wField.set(this, value);
   }else{
    Method parseMethod = wField.getType().getMethod("valueOf", new Class[]{String.class});
    wField.set(this, parseMethod.invoke(wField, value));
   }
 }
```

Any ideas how to avoid that workaround?

Do you think `java.lang.String` should support the method `valueOf(String)`?

Thanks.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that all of these Objects (except enums) have unary String constructors. So you could switch to using those in all cases and only using `valueOf` for your enums, if that seems somehow cleaner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've noticed, there is no `String.valueOf(String)`. However, I wouldn't consider your implementation a hack, just recognition of the minor inconsistency in the JDK classes.

For more robust String to Object conversion, you might consider using [PropertyEditors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html), which directly support String to Object conversion - implementation for primitive types and Strings provided by default.) Your parse method will then be consistent, and extendible to handle different types. Better still are the conversion classes in [Commons Convert](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/convert/), and [Spring 3 Type Converters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert), as these are focused purely on conversion, and not GUI editing of properties.

Comment: PropertyEditors are in use by Spring, no? They are definitely what you want here, btw.

Comment: Spring does use PropertyEditors, but with Spring 3.x also the new type conversion classes which are "cleaner" than PropertyEditors.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to avoid that workaround?

This largely depends on the implementation of `parseMethod`.

> Do you think java.lang.String should support the method valueOf(String)?

What for? That would be a no-op, simply returning its parameter.

Comment: parseMethod IS valueOf(String). So I didn't implement that by myself.

yes, it would be a no-op, but it would make valueOf more general useable IMHO. at least in this case. but maybe there's another option i'm not aware of.

Comment: @fabb, it would be usable only in a special case of reflection, so most Java developers would never need it. And IMHO the workaround you show is something one can live with.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think `java.lang.String` should support the method `valueOf(String)`?

No. It would have almost no value outside of reflection, and reflection shouldn't be encouraged anyway (*Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 53: Prefer interfaces to reflection*).

Comment: Oh come on, just because Bloch said it doesn't make it true. Reflection is a powerful and wonderful tool. I will concede that this particular instance doesn't seem like its greatest moment, however.

Answer (score 0):

**In Case Of String:**

Method parseMethod = wField.getType().getMethod("valueOf", new Class[]{Object.class});

wField.set(this, parseMethod.invoke(wField, value));